# Wordpress Contact form 7 : Mails are not sending if only recaptcha is used, else working fine

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using wordpress contact form 7 and I inserted recaptcha in that form. I integrated the keys also. But, while checking the captcha( I'm  not robot) and after by clicking on submit, It is loading continuously.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you coding the recaptcha integration yourself or using an existing plugin?

Comment: I am using existing plugin

Comment: Any help? @flauntster

Comment: If there's a problem with the plugin, contact the plugin developer for them to fix it.

Comment: Yes as @FluffyKitten said your best approach will be to contact the developer or seek an alternative, up-to-date plugin which does the same functionality.  You don't really want to touch existing plugins code, as any changes will be overwritten if you update the plugin down the track :)

Comment: Thanks I've used another Plug in, Contact Form 7 Image Captcha. It works fine.